# Lazarus 0.9.30 trimmed menu entries

Tags: windows, delphi, lazarus, freepascal, fpc

I'm using Lazarus 0.9.30 and in both the IDE and the sample applications the menu entries a trimmed:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/94832ba880.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/94832ba880.png)

I can live with this in the IDE, but for the aplications is there something I can do? Adding spaces to the end of the caption has solved the problem only in designer, at runtime the caption is still trimmed.

OS: Windows 7 x86

Lazarus versions tried:

- Lazarus 0.9.30 + FPC 2.4.2
- Lazarus 0.9.31-29752 + FPC 2.4.2 (2011-03-09)
- Lazarus 0.9.31-29752 + FPC 2.4.3 (2011-03-09)

**UPDATE**:

The menu caption are trimmed when using Tahoma 8 for system menus. Changing the font size to 9 solves the problem, but it would be nice to find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is a check in the Editor options (General tab) called "Trim trailing spaces". You could try to uncheck it, though I am not sure this affects the .lfm, and you would need to check if it affects the rest of your code.

You can find more information about the Lazarus editor options [here](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/IDE_Window%3a_Editor_Options/es).

Said this, I would try to download the Lazarus 0.9.31 version from [here](http://www.hu.freepascal.org/lazarus/). I have that version installed and have no problem with menu trimming.

HTH

Comment: The trailing spaces of the menu item caption (in the `Properties` tab) are not removed regardless of the option state, and the behavior is the same when the option is unchecked.

Comment: guessed so but it was worth a try... Have you tried with the Lazarus 0.9.31 version?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I was setting the caption in the designer, but the actual value used at runtime was defined in code, so adding a space at the end of the caption is the workaround for the moment.

Comment: Something special about your Windows setup? Changed system font (e.g. because of high res monitor) ?